# Rails internationalization is not working in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-i18n

I have a non-AR model, which I use for a form/composition object.

There are lots input fields, which I collect in order to do some data manipulation inside AR transaction.

I use I18n for internationalization.

yml:

```
pl:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      catalog/checkout:
        name: Imię
```

form:

```
= f.input :name,
  required: true,
  label: I18n.t(:'.activemodel.attributes.catalog/checkout.name')
```

The issue is that in development and production modes (locally) I see the input having proper label taken from `config/locales`, but on production server it says

> `"translation missing: pl.activemodel.attributes.catalog/checkout.name"`

It happens exclusively with this non-AR model - everywhere else I18n works perfectly fine.

Any thoughts?

## EDIT

Logged into the production server's console:

```
I18n.reload!
#=> nil
I18n.t(:'.activemodel').keys
#=> [:errors, :attributes] # attributes is what wee need
```

But

```
I18n.t(:'.activemodel.attributes')
#=> "translation missing: pl.activemodel.attributes"
```

Wth?...

## EDIT #2

I have to notice, that having

```
pl:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      catalog/checkout:
    errors:
      models:
        catalog/checkout:
          attributes:
```

`errors` section works as expected, problems are only with `activemodel.attributes`

Comment: Would this `I18n.t('activemodel.attributes.catalog/checkout.name')` works ?

Comment: it is in no way different from what I have, so it works in dev mode, and will not id production

Comment: Oh okay. Random guess- did you included `config/locales/pl.yml` file on production ?

Comment: I have huge amount of translations - all work except for this one - sure I have :)

Comment: log in the console and run `I18n.reload!`.

Comment: thought about that like a second ago, but still not sure if that is the solution (even if that would work)

Comment: i have the same problem, try this, if its works, i can explain. Also do you use `vim` as editor?

Comment: @Зелёный  
it shows strange result in production server at all. see the edit. I am using not cool thing - ST3

Comment: i give up, never seen an issue like this.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko do you have this `extend ActiveModel::Translation` in your `ActiveModel`?

Comment: `extend ActiveModel::Translation` does something else, and translations work for `errors`,  for example (as I say in [my issue on Github](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/330)). Something is wrong with just `activemodel.attributes` part

Comment: Maybe try removing that unicode character and see if there's any difference

Comment: nope, has nothing to do with that character 100%, unfortunately.