# Business logic dependent on model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a `User` model that has an `introduced_by` attribute. Based on that attributes value, I calculate my commission differently. What would be the best, most flexible way of doing this?

Should I do a switch, or maybe put everything in a flat file? Also, should I create a `Commission` model?

Comment: hey Mike, having answer that solves  your issue please check it as right answer by accepting it (checkmark on the left side of the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very broad question, as there is no code and no example. However, it seems to be the perfect case of a `Strategy` design pattern.

What I would do, is to create a class that represents the strategy for every specific range of attribute values.

E.g

```
PersonalCommission
CompanyCommission
HighValueCommission
DefaultCommission
```

Each class has a single method, let's say `calculate` that you can call passing an instance of the object and that returns the value of the commission.

Wherever you need to perform the calculation, just initialize a new `Commission` strategy object based on the User attribute and call `calculate` on it.

You don't even have to use a switch, as you can initialize the class dynamically.

```
strategy = "#{user.introduced_by}Commission".constantize
strategy.new.compute(whatever)
```

Of course, that's just a very simple example you'll have to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. Not using a switch complies with the "Tell don't ask" philosophy.

Comment: good stuff, good answer! Hey Simone, if you have a minute, could you please take a look at [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083384/rails-internationalization-is-not-working-in-production-mode). It is not urgent, it's just something I don't understand. Thx in advance!

Comment: Actually, I have two more questions. in which folder should I put the different strategies? If I have a default Commission Strategy, should I still have a commission Interface , or can I have my defaultCommission as the base implementation?

Comment: Please open different questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simone, I just did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121051/strategy-pattern-files-location-rails