# Strategy pattern files location Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a couple of questions: 
following the perfect response that I got on that question [Business logic dependent on model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090617/business-logic-dependent-on-model-attribute).

I plan on usin a Strategy pattern, and I was wondering where I (in which folder) should put the classes files? should they go in the models folder?
Also, I have a default behavior, do I still need to create a Interface class and have my default strategy derived from this, or I define my default strategy as the base strategy?

Comment: You can store PORO's in any folder as long as it's a child of the /app directory. In your case you could consider creating a /strategies folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a subjective answer, therefore it's likely it will be closed at some point.

As I provided an answer to the original question, let me try to answer this one.

There are two possible places where you may store this file:

- `app`
- `lib`

In this specific case, I'd go with the `lib` folder. For each Rails app I'm working on I generally have a specific folder within lib called with the same name of the project that represents the namespace where I store the business logic specific for my app.

For instance, if my project is called `whatever`, I have a `lib/whatever` along with a file `lib/whatever.rb` that is the root of my namespace.

```
module Whatever
end
```

Each file within the `lib/whatever` folder is nested within that namespace. In this case, you may create a folder specific for your commission strategies at `lib/whatever/commissions` and create the following files

```
# lib/whatever/commissions/alpha_strategy.rb
class Whatever::Commissions::AlphaStrategy
end

# lib/whatever/commissions/beta_strategy.rb
class Whatever::Commissions::BetaStrategy
end
```

To reduce the number of files, you can simply have a `lib/whatever/commissions.rb` file that will store all the strategies. This works well when the implementation of each strategy is relatively short.

```
# lib/whatever/commissions.rb
module Whatever::Commissions
  class AlphaStrategy
  end

  class BetaStrategy
  end
end
```

Let's see, instead, why I would not place these files in `app`. Again, this response is subjective and it's based on my personal experience with fairly large and complex Rails applications.

I've seen using `/app` for storing a lot of stuff. A common pattern, for example, is to create an `app/workers` folder within app. Which may make sense as workers are global (still, you can store them in the `lib`). In your case, what you are creating is really oriented towards a single model, therefore having a dedicated folder in `/app` is probably too much. Also, if you use a generic name such as `strategies` that will not be meaningful at all.

So why not `app/models` then? Well, in fact this may be the second alternative. However, I prefer to only store models in that folder and models, to me, means only persistence-related features.

What you are creating is not directly related to persistence. It uses a persisted object (an instance of a model), but it has nothing to do with saving data to the database. Therefore, it doesn't really make sense in the `app/models`.

In a small project you can likely save it in `app/models`, but I've worked with projects where you have over 30 models, and if you store all those not-persistence-related features in `app/models` then your folder will slowly become a mess.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Simone for taking the time for this great answer. That makes perfect sense. I thought that the lib folder was only meant to be used for outside programs. What about the second part of the question regarding the default strategy implementation? Again thanks a lot for your valuable time.